# How does Electrum's "send change to lightning" work?

Tags: lightning-network, electrum, change

In Electrum, when sending to a non-Lightning ₿ address, I can choose the "[send change to lightning](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/pull/8604)" option. How does this work?